# How do I dynamically display contents in tables in Java

Tags: java, json, dynamic, awt

I need to display some content in a tabular form dynamically in Java. The content includes data that is fetched from an API in JSON format. At the end of each row I need to display a checkbox as well. The number of rows is dynamic and the columns are fixed. How do I do this?

The table will have the following columns:

1. Index
2. Username
3. Upload date
4. Percentage
5. Matched results
6. [Checkbox]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer to this problem. We can dynamically create a table using the class DefaultTableModel and the Java swing class JTable.

```
model = new DefaultTableModel();
```

Set the columns

```
model.setColumnIdentifiers(new Object[]{"Index","User","Reg no.","Match"});
jTable1.setModel(model);
jTable1.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
jTable1.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
jScrollPane1.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
jScrollPane1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
```

Add the rows from the JSON response

```
for(int i=0;i< jsonArr.size();i++)
{
    str = jsonArr.get(i).toString();
    jsonObj = (JSONObject)parser.parse(str);
    String sub = jsonObj.get("subid").toString();
    String uname = jsonObj.get("username").toString();
    String regno = jsonObj.get("regno").toString();
    String percent = jsonObj.get("percent").toString();
    model.addRow(new Object[]{sub,uname,regno,percent});            
}
```